# Animation after applied modifier

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, modifiers, transforms

I have a plane, that transforms into cylinder after simple deform modifier:

[image]

I can now animate this transformation. However, after that I would also like to animate some adjustments to my cylinder mesh, but I need to apply the modifier to get mesh on cylinder and after applying previous animation is destroyed.

[image]

How can I record both animations? How do people do this in general? As I understand, applying modifiers ruins everything, but how can I get control over mesh without applying them?

I start thinking about some tricks like duplicating object and somehow replacing old one, or just recording separate animation videos and then merging them in video editor (but I must preserve camera position and angle)..

Comment: what kind of adjustments? yes maybe replacing the object is the easiest trick

Comment: @moonboots proportional editing (moving) of faces

Comment: I do not understand why you believe you must apply modifiers. The Blender User can use multiple modifiers . Yes it can be difficult to manage and not trivial. Making Object 2 [Rendered] and Object 1 [Not Rendered] is definitely useful technique. You can choose the simplest route that works for you. Yet there are many modifiers, that you might be using ,now or in the future.  So what you consider this week to be a little complexity, may slither in .. and next week you might see it as quite easy.

Comment: You can try using the "Surface Deform" modifier. Create a copy of your object and apply the simple deformer. Then in the original object add the Surface Deform modifier and select the copy as the target object. In the original object, go into object mode and create a vertex group containing all the object's vertex and select that group in the Surface Deform modifier. Click "bind" and set the strength to 1. Now you can select the copy and go into object mode and move around the vertices, and the original object will follow the deformation.

Comment: (continuing) You can animate the strength of the modifier so it only starts deforming after the plane is bent into a cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate [render visibility] with Keyframes. The graph window can show render visibility of multiple objects at once. This may address part of your issue. Other people can address other concerns or you can submit a different question.

Of course in Blender there are always 33 ways to do something.  You can use layers as well or simply move an object out of view of the camera.  You can also consider other visual cues such as viewing only edges .. and or keyframed scale factors.

[image]

The yellow arrows shows the effects of putting a keyframe on render visibility of an object. Please Click on the image to see a larger version.  By having two or more objects you can instruct Blender to render one of them and to not render the other ones, saving compute time.  Please do not confuse this with 3D View Visibility.  This is not a tutorial.